# UINavigationController is pushing like modal on iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard, segue

My first viewController has a uitableView inside with a segue made on storyboard dragging the cell to the next view and selecting "show".

On the first viewController the navigation bar shows up just fine.

The push works perfectly on iOS 8, coming from the right side.

On iOS 7 it seems like the push is working on MODAL style, the next view controller comes from the bottom and the navigation bar is gone!

Anyone seem something like that?

Comment: Any code to provide?

Comment: Code should not be needed since this example and the segues are created using storyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your segue type to "Push" in Deprecated section. Look at the attached screenshot
[image]

Comment: This works. But is not the solution I would like to give. Anyway I will keep like this until I get back to that to dig some more

Comment: Until you address to iOS 7 SDK, you can use this deprecated segue types.